# Need help formatting html from my code-behind

Tags: c#, html

I have the following code snippet, but I'm banging my head up against the wall trying to get the errors out of it.

I'm getting the following design time compile errors:

```
; expected
The name button does not exist in the current context.
```

Those same two messages also repeat for the DisplayReceipt.

Here is my code snippet being assigned in my **code behind** for html.

**Can somebody please help me out?**

```
Image_ID = "<input id='" + fuelticket.Image_ID + "' type="button" onclick='" + DisplayReceipt(fuelticket.Image_ID)"'>";
```

Comment: I think you need to change the "" around button to '' and add a + after .Image_ID) at the end.

Comment: You shouldn't be doing this from your code behind in the first place.  Put it on the markup and only modify the few things that aren't static from the code behind.

Comment: Try to stay away mixing html in c# code.

Comment: Your question is incomplete, please mention that DisplayReceipt is supposed to be rendered on client as its a javascript function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to escape the quotes:

```
Image_ID = "<input id='" + fuelticket.Image_ID + "' type=\"button\" onclick='DisplayReceipt(" + fuelticket.Image_ID + ")'>";
```

Or use `string.Format()` to make things a bit cleaner:

```
Image_ID = string.Format("<input id='{0}' type=\"button\" onclick='DisplayReceipt({0})'>", fuelticket.Image_ID);
```

Comment: Getting closer... With that exact snippet you provided, I'm now getting "The name DisplayReceipt does not exist in the current context" and at the very endwhere the "'>"; is, I'm getting "; expected".

Comment: @sagesky36 - updated. You needed a `+` after the call to DisplayReceipt(). If it still can't resolve `DisplayReceipt`, you'll need to post more code.

Comment: Getting even closer Jon... The only error I get now is "the name 'DisplayReceipt' does not exist in the current context".

Comment: I should mention that DisplayReceipt is a jQuery function that will be executed.

Comment: OK, then it needs to be inside the quotes. Updated.

Comment: Can you updated your edit please so I can copy it from there? Trying that out didn't work for me...

Comment: Both worked fine... Thanks so much for your help. I'll keep these in mind going forward.

Answer (score 1):

To make it work use the below code:

```
Image_ID = String.Format("<input id=\"{0}\" type=\"button\" onclick=\"{1}\">", fuelticket.Image_ID, DisplayReceipt(fuelticket.Image_ID));
```

The above looks more clear and optionally you can also use `@` for the string so you don't have to escape any special characters.

```
Image_ID = String.Format(@"<input id="{0}" type="button" onclick="DisplayReceipt({0})">", fuelticket.Image_ID));
```